# Firefox Developer Edition Pick element not working

Tags: firefox

Is it me only or does the Ctrl + Shift + C to pick an element in the Firefox Developer Tools not working any more?
I use the latest Firefox Developers edition and yesterday I noticed I cannot pick elements with the chortcut, I have to click on the little "pick element" icon in the top left.

Comment: Doesnt anyone know about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FF fixed it them selves with the latest release.